# What are some practical problems that parallel computing, f#, and GPU-parallel processing might solve

Tags: f#, parallel-processing, brute-force, wifi, stream-processing

[Recently WiFi encryption was brute forced by using the parellel processing power of the modern GPU.](http://www.tomshardware.com/news/nvidia-gpu-wifi-hack,6483.html)  What other real-life problems do you think will benefit from similar techniques?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Computational fluid dynamics
- Physics processing
- Ray tracing
- Data mining
- Medical imaging
- Control engineering software
- Digital signal processing
- Bioinformatics

In fact, check out [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU#Applications) for a lot more examples of where GPGPU has been used.

To name a few.

Answer (score 5):

Image processing which is just fancier signal processing which is massively parallel math.

given that, perhaps face recognition, voice recognition, video decode/encode, audio decode/encode, encryption/decryption

Answer (score 4):

Most batch-processing tasks can be parallised and are well suited to the stream processors in GPUs. Folding. Seti. All those gubbins are already working well on GPUs.